How to select the right bin size for power spectrum density graph?
My sampling frequency in 25.6 kHz, I am varying the window size to adjust the bin size.

The length of the dataset is inversely proportional to the resolution bandwidth, which means the ability to distinguish closely spaced frequencies. Without further windowing (therefore a rectangular window) the resolution bandwidth in Hz is simply the reciprocal of the capture duration in seconds. Windowing will increase this bandwidth further (typically between 1.5 and 2x depending on window used) at the benefit of significantly increasing the dynamic range (ability to distinguish signals at different frequencies but with large differences in power).
A direct FFT (windowed and zero padded by 4 to 10x to make scalloping loss insignificant) is my recommended approach for measuring single tones and very narrowband signals (and for that just scale by the sum of the window for an accurate frequency measurement consistent in the same magnitude units of the input with a two sided spectrum).
For power spectral density measurements where the goal is to get an accurate measurement of signals with power distributed over bandwidth (in contrast to single tones), with an accurate measurement of the power density (such as dBm/Hz), I recommend the Welch method which is available in Matlab, Octave and Python’s scipy.signal. The tools all compensate for the windows used (default is Hann but you can pass in other windows if desired) so easily provide the accurate results directly. The parameter ‘nperseg’ will adjust the resolution bandwidth of the measurement- increasing nperseg will result in tighter frequency resolution but come at the expense of noise in the result. Welch works by taking smaller overlapping FFT’s and averaging the result so at the expense of a wider resolution bandwidth provides a much cleaner measurement result of broad band signals and noise floors. This is ideal for when an actual Power Spectral Density (PSD) is desired vs a Power Spectrum.
Note: These details and more with specific approaches to waveform analysis and the gotchas are all part of my presentation coming up at the end of this month for the 2024 DSP Online Conference.

Spectrum bin size is a bit of a misnomer. The DFT is a sampled DTFT, so the DFT sample points aren't really "bins" per say (see What is the "general effect" when a signal's frequency component falls onto the boundary of two neighboring DFT bins? and the answers to that question).
While it's true that there will be spectral leakage if your signals don't fall directly on DFT sample points, the majority of the energy will fall into the DFT sample points nearest the frequencies in the recorded signal. So, the recommended maximum bin spacing, in my opinion, would be roughly half the spacing between your two closest frequencies so that there is a DFT sample point between them. For example, if you had 1 kHz, 1.5 kHz, and 2.5 kHz sinusoids in your signal, your closest frequencies are spaced 500 Hz apart, so you would want your DFT bin spacing to be at most roughly 250 Hz apart.
Now, your true frequency resolution is going to be $\frac{f_{s}}{N}$ where $f_{s}$ is your sampling frequency, in your case 25.6 kHz, and $N$ is the length of your dataset (you can beat this, but it's more complicated). If your dataset is already sufficiently long to resolve your closest spaced frequencies, then a simple magnitude-squared FFT will do the trick. If your dataset is so long that you can beat the $\frac{f_{s}}{N}$ limit by a fair amount, you might try something like Welch's method to smooth out the estimate a little more. If, however, your dataset is not long enough to resolve your closest spaced frequencies, you would need a superresolution technique to achieve this. I've detailed how to compute some of these methods quite extensively (see Computing modern spectral estimation techniques with FFTs). My recommendation for starters would be an autoregressive (AR) model spectral estimate as it is pretty plug and play and there are multiple methods for estimating the AR parameters that can give better results. But you will likely find that several methods of estimating AR model spectral estimates will give you very fine resolution compared to DFT based methods.
